# should singletons be avoided

Tags: c#, winforms

[evil singletons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx)

Should I avoid using the singleton pattern?

Edit: Okay I wasn't expecting to get closed down.

I guess I should clarify a bit, I have been using singletons for:

1)storing a connection string to a database, or the role of the current user.

2) time consuming data to retrieve from a remote data server - it has a very slow connection.

Comment: Once you use Dependency Injection there is rarely a need for the classical Singleton pattern. You just tell your container to always give you the same instance. This solves some of the problems of a singleton(At a glance it solves all problems mentioned in that article). The inherent problem of global mutable state obviously remains in some(less severe) form.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: Neither of your examples needs to enforce that they are a singleton. Create an interface for it (Say `IRetrieveDataFromServer`) and then let DI pass it into the constructor of your type.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - thanks for the tips, I'll look for some examples.

Answer (score 2):

The singleton pattern is not evil in itself, but if you overuse it, you will notice that it's not a solution for everything.

Like any pattern it has its use, but you should only use it when you need it, not everywhere that you possibly can.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to overuse it. You can  to use it and wait for it to become evil.

Answer (score 0):

You should if you agree with [Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/).

Nowadays I think Singleton would be the pattern most likely to be expunged from the Gang of Four book.

A fan?  Really?